# Property 'subscriptionPeriod' not found on object of type 'SKProd in FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-fbsdk

I am very new to xcode environment, I have integrate the Facebook SDK by exactly same steps shown in [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#settings).
Generate App id, made changes to Info.plist file, init pod file, adding **pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'** and **pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'** into the pod file , pod install.

But after setting all things when i build the project, got 6 issue , all are related to the Pods>FBSDKCoreKit>FBSDKPaymentObserver.m>-logTransactionEvent:

[image]

**Podfile Code:-**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'E_Commerce' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for E_Commerce
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

#target 'E_Commerce-tvOSTests' do
#    inherit! :search_paths
#    # Pods for testing
#end

  target 'E_CommerceTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'E_Commerce-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for E_Commerce-tvOS

  target 'E_Commerce-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**AppDelegate.m code:**

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file/Users/shailendrakumar/Desktop/Ajeet Data/Projects/E_Commerce/ios/E_Commerce/AppDelegate.m in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNGoogleSignin.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//for facebook
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"E_Commerce"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
// For gmail
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  return
  [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                      openURL:url
            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                   annotation:annotation
   ];
}

//for facebook
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  return handled;
}

@end
```

**FBSDKCoreKit version is 4.35.0.**

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: If we look at `SKProduct`, `subscriptionPeriod` is available since iOS 11.2 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/2936884-subscriptionperiod?language=objc) and there is correctly a protection `if (@available(iOS 11.2, *))` and `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_11_2`, so strangely you shouldn't have the issue.

Comment: @Larme , yea strange, but it is still showing error, even i reinstall the FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit again, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

i have same error with you and i tried comment these error code lines and build success, i think if you don't need payment of FBSDK you can try it, hope it help you.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with XCode version. Minimum requirement says XCode version 9.2. Ref: https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/98